# JavaScript: Write a function that takes an input character and returns that character repeated 5 times using recursion

Tags: javascript, function, recursion, arguments, repeat

Write a function that takes an input character and returns that character repeated 5 times using recursion. For example, if the input is 'g', then the output should be 'ggggg'.

I tried the code below:

```
function repeater(char) {

  let newStr = ''; 

  if (newStr.length === 5){
    return newStr; 
  }

  else {
    newStr += char; 
  }

  return repeater(char); 
}

// To check if you've completed the challenge, uncomment these console.logs!
console.log(repeater('g')); // should return 'ggggg'
//console.log(repeater('j')); 'jjjjj'
```

My code returns: `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When would `newStr.length === 5` ever be true? It'll always be an empty list because it's set right about that line. Did you mean `char.length === 5`?

Comment: It would help you see what your code is doing if you'd try adding `console.log()` or some other sort of tracing to the code at key points, printing current values of variables and indicating the decisions being made.

Comment: Each time you call your repeater function, you instantiate a new let variable newStr. Your return means a memory  issue, since it's being called infinite times.

Answer (score 2):

Cause `newStr` is a local variable that does not get passed on in the recursive call. Therefore, a new `newStr` will be created on each call, and its length will always be 0.  To resolve that, either pass on the string, or the length:

```
  function repeat(char, result = "") { 
    if(result.length / char.length >= 3) return result;
    return repeat(char, result + char); // ²
 }

 // a call goes like:
 // repeat("g", "")
 // repeat("g", "g")
 // repeat("g", "gg")
 // repeat("g", "ggg")

 // OR

 function repeat(char, count = 3) { /*¹*/
    if(count <= 1) return char;
    return char + repeat(char, count - 1);
 }

 // repeat("g", 3)
 // "g" + repeat("g", 2)
 // "g" + "g" + repeat("g", 1)
 // "g" + "g" + "g"
```

Or if this should only work with one char given (as the task says):

```
 function repeat(char) {
   if(char.length >= 3) return char;
   return repeat(char + char[0]); // ²
 }
```

---

Note: The functions above won't return 5 repeats. Thats left as an exercise to you :)

If we take the assignment aside you could just do `"g".repeat(5)` though ...

---

¹: The `= 3` is a so called "default argument". That means that `repeat("g")` equals `repeat("g", 3)`. The advantage is that you can reuse this for different lengths, `repeat("g", 10)` will repeat g 10 times.

²: Thats a tail call. If you place the recursive call at the last line and return it, the engine can optimize the recursion into a loop, which is way faster *and* does not reach a maximum call stack size (infinite recursion is still bad, try to always avoid getting into it. `newStr.length === 5` for example is dangerous, as a string of length 6 would run forever. Therefore I'd recommend using `>=` or `<=` (as I did above)).

Answer (score 1):

You could take a default value of `5` and call the recursion until no more calls are a available.

```js
function repeater(char, count = 5) {
    if (!count) return '';                   // exit condition
    return char + repeater(char, count - 1); // repeating part
}

console.log(repeater('x'));
```

Comment: @JonasWilms, yes and no, because the exit condition checks not for a count left, but for no count. that is, if you call the function with count zero, you get no character, as opposite from your example, you return with zero a character, which is in my view not intended (and maybe not possible, if not taken the second parameter). in my case the second parameter can be used with zero.

Answer (score 0):

One thing in your code is you are calling repeater outside else condition which means it will be called infinitely. Second is you are declaring newStr inside the function. You may want to do something like this.

```
function repeater(char, oldStr) {
    let newStr = oldStr || '';
    if (newStr.length === 5) {
        return newStr;
    } else {
        newStr += char;
        return repeater(char, newStr);
    }
 }
```

Comment: if you run both console.log from my original code ... I think your code returns the wrong output for the second console.log

Comment: @PineNuts0 I see what you are saying. That is because I am not re initializing the newStr. I modified the code to accept second parameter which will contain the result from previous iteration. If there is no second parameter it is going to start with empty string.